# Fix "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" at server side

Tags: ssh, upgrade, ssh-keys, fingerprint

Note that the question is to fix the "REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!" problem ***at server side***.

I know the implication and I know exactly what I'm doing --

- I'm reinstalling/upgrading my server, and want the process as smooth as possible.
- During the reinstalling/upgrading, I might need to boot into the old or new version back and forth many times.

Thus I need to eliminate the warning from the client side as much as possible. Otherwise, I need to flip my `~/known_hosts` file back and forth needlessly.

So how to set my new server's fingerprint / ECDSA key the same as before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update: After thinking about it a bit, I think I'll change my recommendation to copying just the key files, and the config entries that refer to them. The key files are all in /etc/ssh/, and are named `ssh_host_<keytype>_key` and each has a corresponding public key file with a `.pub` extension. Here's an example with dsa, ecdsa, ed25519, and rsa keys:

```
$ cd /etc/ssh
$ ls -l ssh_host_*key*
-rw------- 1 root root  668 Apr  8 03:43 ssh_host_dsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  606 Apr  8 03:43 ssh_host_dsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root  227 Apr  8 03:43 ssh_host_ecdsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  178 Apr  8 03:43 ssh_host_ecdsa_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root  411 Apr  8 03:43 ssh_host_ed25519_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   98 Apr  8 03:43 ssh_host_ed25519_key.pub
-rw------- 1 root root 1679 Apr  8 03:43 ssh_host_rsa_key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  398 Apr  8 03:43 ssh_host_rsa_key.pub
```

And there may be `HostKey` entries in /etc/ssh/sshd_config telling sshd to use them. In my case, the files are just the default ones, so the relevant lines are commented out:

```
$ grep HostKey /etc/ssh/sshd_config 
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey /etc/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key
```

You should be able to clone the key files from the original server (be sure to match the old permissions), and if there are uncommented `HostKey` entries you should add those to the new config's `sshd_config` file as well. If you have any other non-default settings there, you'll want to copy them as well.

I'd originally recommended just cloning the entire `/etc/ssh/` directory from the old server to the new one. This has the advantage that it automatically copies any additional settings changes you've made. The disadvantage (and the reason I've decided not to recommend it) is the old config may not include changes that've been made to improve security.

For example, your old config might not have a /etc/ssh/moduli file with custom Diffie-Hellman moduli, and the new OS version might not auto-generate one. This would be a problem because the default modulus isn't very secure, and since everyone used to use the same one, an attack on it was an attack on everyone. See [here](https://entropux.net/article/openssh-moduli/) and [here](https://weakdh.org) for some more information.

If your "old" server config isn't too ancient, it should already have a custom moduli file, but that's just an example; there are probably other things that should be updated, so using a mostly-new config is probably better. BTW, using different moduli won't cause an "ID CHANGED" type error, so if that file exists in the old server, you don't need to copy it.

Comment: @xpt Actually, on reflection I've decided to change my recommendation to only cloning the key files. See the answer for my reasoning.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot Gordon for being thoughtful and meticulous! I'll change my practice accordingly.